# Fixed Top Menu Bar Overlapping Inline Hyperlink Jump

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor, css-position

I have a fixed menu bar at the top of my site.  I have a page that has inline linking by adding a hash tag to the URL making it jump to that particular element.  The problem is the element it jumps to is hidden being this fixed menu bar.  Is there a way to move the jump down a bit?  Here is an example:

[Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cblaze22/dezaH/8/show/light)

Comment: Can you share some codes in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you cannot do that via html, you'd need some JS, or even CSS, depending on your code.
Can you post a sample on jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, add another (hidden) element below it and simply link to that one instead:

```
<a href="#element1-target">click me</a>

<!-- further down the page is the content -->
<div id="#element1">Here is what users will be reading!</div>
<div id="#element1-target"
      style="visibility:hidden;{make this lower down below the actual text}"></div>
```

---

My only question though, is if your header bar is blocking your text that the page 'jumps' to, wouldn't you want the page to link to *higher* than the target?

---

Given your question is vague and I don't think your example shows what your problem is, this *should* do what (*i think*) you're trying to do.

:)

Comment: That means I have to add hidden elements everywhere.  It is a work around, but hopefully someone posts something better.